# change order of double sums

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, summation

I need to prove that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \sum_{j=k}^n C(i,j,n) \log(n+k) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \left(\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}C(i,j,n) \log(n+k)\right)$$

where $$C(i,j,n)={n \choose i}{n \choose j}\frac{(-1)^{i+j-1}}{j-i}$$

---

I tried the following :

Let $S(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}C(i,j,n)log(n+k)\right)$ then each term of $ S (n) $
have a coefficient of the form $ log (n + l) $  with $ 1 \leq l \leq n $. From the above we can write $ S (n) $ as $S(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n log(n+l)a_l$. For every $ 1 \leq l \leq n $ I tried to find every $ a_l $, but i couldn't prove the equality.

Comment: Instead, generalize and prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \sum_{j=k}^n f(i,j,k,n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \sum_{k=i+1}^{j} f(i,j,k,n)$$ whenever $f$ is a function with the appropriate domain so that each evaluation makes sense.  (in other words, this equality should mostly be seen as a property of summation notation, not a property of the summands)

Answer (score 2):

We can do it as follows : \begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}}{\color{red}{\sum_{j=k}^{n}}{a_{i,j,k}}}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\color{red}{\sum_{j=k}^{n}}{\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}}{a_{i,j,k}}}}\\ &=\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}}{\color{red}{\sum_{j=k}^{n}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{a_{i,j,k}}}}\\ &=\color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}}{\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{j}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{a_{i,j,k}}}}\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{j}}{\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}}{a_{i,j,k}}}}\\ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\sum_{j=k}^{n}{a_{i,j,k}}}}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}}{\color{green}{\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}}{a_{i,j,k}}}}\end{aligned}

In the third and fifth line, we've used the formula for exchanging double sums : $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{j}{u_{i,j}}}=\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}{a_{i,j}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=i}^{n}{u_{i,j}}} $$

If you're not familiar with it, here is one simple proof using pure algebra : \begin{aligned}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{n}{u_{i,j}}}&=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{k}{u_{i,j}}}-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}{u_{i,j}}}\right)}  \\ &=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{k}{u_{i,j}}-\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}{u_{i,j}}\right)}}\\ &=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{u_{i,k}}} \\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{n}{u_{i,j}}}&=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{j}{u_{i,j}}}\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful. Can you recommend a book or text where I can read about multiple sums?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be fixed. The triple sum is extended over all triples $(k,i,j)$ with $1\le k \le n, 0 \le i \le k - 1$, and $k\le j \le n$. Given such a triple, $1\le k \le j \le n$ and $0 \le i \le j-1$ (since $0 \le i\le k-1$ and $k \le j$). In particular, we have $1 \le j \le n$, $0 \le i \le j-1$, and $i + 1 \le k \le j$. Conversely, if the latter three inequalities hold, then as $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, $0 \le i \le k-1$ (from $0 \le i$ and $i + 1\le k$) and $k\le j \le n$. Thus $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \sum_{j = k}^n a_{k,i,j} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{i = 0}^{j-1}\sum_{k = i+1}^j a_{k,i,j}$$ for any triply-indexed sequence $(a_{k,i,j})$ of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=k}^na_{i,j,k}}
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=k}^na_{i-1,j,k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq i\leq k\leq j\leq n}}a_{i-1,j,k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j\sum_{k=i}^ja_{i-1,j,k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\sum_{k=i+1}^ja_{i,j,k}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index $i$ to start with $i=1$.
- In (2) we write the summation indices as inequality chain. This is a convenient representation to find the index transformation in the next step.
- In (3) we derive the wanted index transformation based upon the inequality chain.
- In (4) we shift the index $i$ back to start again with $i=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful. Can you recommend a book or text where I can read about multiple sums?

Comment: @AndrésOrtiz: You're welcome. I recommend to go through chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R. L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik.